# Add Chipmunk as a static library in Xcode?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5, chipmunk

The "libObjectiveChipmunk.a" library is marked red (missing) in my project using cocos2d v3. I have tried re-installing the cocos2dv3/ creating a new project, however, the issue persists.
I can see the lib_chipmunk.xctemplate in "/Users/abhineet/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d v3.x/Support/Libraries". Somehow the install script is not able to create a static library.

How can i add the static library? Can it be downloaded from somewhere and added to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks" ?

Comment: ignore that it is red - do you get an actual linker error? If so post that error, otherwise ignore it

Comment: @LearnCocos2D there is no linker error and the physics engine seems to work, so, I will take your suggestion and ignore it. I freaked out cause i thought that was causing the build process while archiving to fail. I ve posted another question stating the exact error causing the build during archive to fail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416971/arc-semantic-issue-multiple-methods-named-setrotation-while-archiving-only

Comment: two different pair of shoes ;) google xcode red library, it's a long standing issue, just ignore the color