# ARC semantic issue "multiple methods named 'setRotation' " while archiving only

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

My project in cocos2dv3 is throwing **ARC Sematic Issue**
Multiple methods named 'setRotation:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes 
while archiving(release mode). It runs fine while deploying to simulator/device (debug mode).
In release mode compiler gets confused between the implementation of rotation in `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` and `CCNode`.
When I got the error in `CCBAnimationManager.m` , I typecasted the object calling the selector setRotation to (`CCNode`*) but then the error crept up in `CCActionInterval`. I'm hoping there is a better solution than typecasting everywhere in cocos2d library.

What am i doing wrong? 
Thankyou for your time.

**EDIT**

```
@interface CCAction : NSObject <NSCopying> {
    id          __unsafe_unretained _originalTarget;
    id          __unsafe_unretained _target;
    NSInteger   _tag;
}
@property (nonatomic,readonly,unsafe_unretained) id target;
@property (nonatomic,readonly,unsafe_unretained) id originalTarget;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite,assign) NSInteger tag;
```

in

```
CCAction.m
@synthesize tag = _tag, target = _target, originalTarget = _originalTarget;


-(void) startWithTarget:(id)aTarget
{
    _originalTarget = _target = aTarget;
}

-(void) startWithTarget:(id)aTarget
{
    _originalTarget = _target = aTarget;
}
```

*Class Hierarchy*

```
@interface CCActionFiniteTime : CCAction <NSCopying> 
@interface CCActionInterval: CCActionFiniteTime <NSCopying>
@interface CCBRotateTo : CCActionInterval <NSCopying>

CCBRotateTo.m {

   -(void) startWithTarget:(CCNode *)aTarget
   {
      [super startWithTarget:aTarget];
      startAngle_ = [self.target rotation];
      diffAngle_ = dstAngle_ - startAngle_;
   }

   -(void) update: (CCTime) t
   {
      [self.target setRotation: startAngle_ + diffAngle_ * t];
   }

}
```

Comment: report it as an issue on github. The fix is simply casting to the appropriate type (base class) wherever this error pops up, as you already noted.

Comment: Post the relevant code causing the problem.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D i will..

Comment: @rmaddy edited the question. but if i typecast here , the problem reappears in CCActionInterval

Comment: Show how the `target` property is declared.

Comment: @rmaddy edited again.

Comment: There's the problem. Change the type from `id` to something more relevant so the compiler knows what to do. And why not use `weak` instead of `unsafe_unretained`?

Comment: @rmaddy this is cocos2dv3 library code so can't really rationalise the use unsafe_unretained over weak. The target is passed down from CCNode runAction which is right at the top of the hierarchy. I will try changing id to CCNode* and follow it all the way through..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem gave me a big headache. Though I've upgraded cocos2d to v2.2 version for my old project (too complex to update to v3), I still got this warning. And any animation I created use rotation in the SpriteBuilder does act oddly, as I described here: 
[Rotation animation issue on iPhone5S with cocos2d 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396648/rotation-animation-issue-on-iphone5s-with-cocos2d-2-0/26397363#26397363)

Finally I used type casting to solve it as following in CCBAnimationManager.m

```
@implementation CCBRotateTo
-(void)startWithTarget:(CCNode *)aTarget
{
    [super startWithTarget:aTarget];
    starAngle_ = [(CCNode *)self.target rotation];
    diffAngle_ = dstAngle_ - startAngle_;
}

-(void)update:(ccTime)t
{
    [(CCNode *)self.target setRotation: startAngle_ + diffAngle_ * t];
}
```

With this change, now I can support arm64 too.

Answer (score 0):

update your cocos2dv3 to latest (RC4 for now).

I was using Xcode 5.0 and cocos2dv3 RC1 with no problem.
But updating Xcode to 5.1 I had this problem.
So I updated the cocos2dv3 to RC4 and now it's working fine.

You can find cocos 2d latest versions from [here](http://cocos2d-objc.org/downloads/).

Comment: @marion: from where i get the rc4 version ...can you give me link for it?

Comment: @DhavalBhadania here you go. it's updated to rc5 now and you can [Get latest version](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/getting-started/#id-latest) or you can still [download rc4 from github](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/tree/release-3.0-rc4)